# How to change textview font in listview with custom adapter?

Tags: java, android

*I have a listview include 2 textview and i have an adapter. how can i change the 
font of textview in custom adapter?*

Comment: post your adapter class code

Comment: Please refere this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to post your code to let us know what you have tried so far. The question you asked is a general question and in my opinion, the answer can be found already in StackOverflow. Just try googling it. Best of luck with your development. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Welcome to android developing....

Answer (score 4):

in the custom adapter and in the getview() method code this:

```
childFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
 titleText.setTypeface(childFont);
```

Comment: Directly using `TypeFace` in `getView()` method  will cause view rendering slow. Instead initialize it once in the adapter constructor and use it in `getView()` method.

Comment: Ok. Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_img_item, null);
  Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/font.ttf");
    holder.textView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
    holder.textView.setTypeface(face1);
    return view;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

Comment: Directly using TypeFace in getView() method will cause view rendering slow. Instead initialize it once in the adapter constructor and use it in getView() method.

Comment: You can pass Typeface from activity to adapter using parameter and  set to the view or In the ( R.id.list_item ) you can set the default font

Comment: This will be a good thing instead of directly initializing it in getView().

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    NotiAdapter.ViewHolder viewholder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_list, null);
        viewholder = new NotiAdapter.ViewHolder();

        viewholder.txtTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);      
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"youtFont.ttf");
        viewholder.txtTitle.setTypeface(custom_font);


        convertView.setTag(viewholder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewholder = (NotiAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewholder.txtTitle.setText(ArNotiList.get(position).getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

And make sure that assets folder contain youtFont.ttf file

Comment: Directly using TypeFace in getView() method will cause view rendering slow. Instead initialize it once in the adapter constructor and use it in getView() method.